# Why Link Selection is visible outside the area of link itself

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have developed a Responsive Website and there are many submenus. The problem is when I click on any menu the selection of the menu is shown below it like in the image

[image]

I have tried using

```
a:focus{outline: 0;}
a:link{outline: 0;}
a:visit{outline: 0;}
a:active{outline: 0;}
a:hover{outline: 0;}
```

but no use.

What can be the problem? You can view the live website at m.zukix.(commercial) => .com . This selection is visible in all devices. This selection is even visible in Google Developer Tools (Ctrl + Shift + I) and setting Mobile view on (Ctrl + Shift + M).

Comment: Cant really help you without telling or showing us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Konstantinos I have already showed you complete work with HTML and CSS on Live website which shows what I have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong padding and/or margin values for your button background.

Comment: I tried removing all of my Padding and Margins from every link but yet no use.